# Android File Transfer not working

Tags: networking, usb, android

My phone is a Moto G4 running Android 7.1.1. Whenever I connect the phone to my Windows PC, nothing happens on either end.

In Windows, File Explorer does not recognise or show the phone. Also, `Device Manager` shows no changes when the phone is plugged/unplugged.

On the phone itself, there is no `USB connection` or `File transfer` popup or notification.

Toggling `Settings > Developer Options > USB debugging` has no effect. Changing options in `Settings > Developer Options > Networking > Select USB configuration` also has no effect. The phone has been restarted multiple times, with and without the cable plugged in.

I'm confident the problem is neither Windows nor the USB cable - tried my daughter's Moto G6 which immediately shows the `USB connection` notification on the phone and was able transfer files between phone and PC without any issue.

Why is this not working on my phone?

Comment: You may need to install Motorola drivers... check the Motorola G4 support page regarding connecting the phone to a PC.  As to the USB debugging, that's not going to do anything unless you're using `adb` _(for example, `adp -p pull` or `adb -p push` for transfers)_.  You can download the `platform-tools` zip from Google's Android SDK download page _(you don't need the SDK, just the `platform-tools` download, which will likely be the smallest of the downloads)_

Comment: I suggest checking the cable.  I have a G5 and I didn't need to install anything.  When I plug it in, I get "Moto G (5)" in the explorer.  After going to the device and changing USB mode from charge to "transfer files".. I get the filesystem on my pc.

Comment: I don't think it's the cable because my daughter's G6 worked...but it's a good comment because maybe the G4 is more "sensitive". Will check.